# finding vector normal - back face algorithm

Tags: graphics, vector-graphics

for back face culling algorithm I need to find the normal vector for each polygon.

given 3 points, I want to find the normal of a plane.

so I know how to do it :

1. find 2 vectors on the plane
2. find their cross vector - which will give me the normal vector (a,b,c)

my question is, does it matter what is the order of the points when I find 2 vectors? 
for ex: given 3 points: p1(0,0,0), p2(5,0,0), p3(10,10,10)

does it matter if I choose vector

```
V1=(p2-p1)=(5, 0, 0)-(0, 0, 0)=(5, 0, 0)
V2=(p3-p1)=(10,10,10)-(0, 0, 0)=(10, 10, 10)
```

or

```
v1=(p1-p2)
v2=(p1-p3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your polygon has vertexes `a`, `b`, `c`.

you calculate the vectors:

```
v1 = a-c
v2 = b-c
```

this refers `a` and `b` to `c`. It would be the same if you decided to refer, say, b and c to a.
calculate the cross product `v1*v2` (this gives a vector perpendicular to v1 and v2) and normalize it.

If, you did calculate (a-b)*(a-c) instead of (b-a)*(c-a), the resulting vector will be mirrored (ie, pointing to the wrong direction).

OT: normalize with/see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root that was developed exactly to calculate face normals

Comment: so as long as I refer to the same point I ll get the correct direction of the normal ? for example I could do: (b-c)*(a-c)  or (c-b)(a-b) etc... will this be always counter clockwise?